# How to find a rectangle in a two-dimensional array with the same corners?

Tags: java, arrays, dimensional

I'm given a two-dimensional array of integers and I need to check if it contains a rectangle that has the same corners as the array corners. for example:

```
3   4   3   5  -9
0   4   4  -8   6
1   1   3  -9   6
4   3  -2   5   6
```

In this array we have a 2X3 rectangle that starts in [0,2]. 
(the corners are 3, -9, 4, 6)

How can I do that efficiently?

Comment: What language are you working on?

Comment: I'm working in Java